# Create new column in df1 by mapping the same column in df2 and apply specific calculation in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs as shown below.

df1:

```
 Date           t_factor      plan           plan_score
0  2020-02-01         5       NaN            0
1  2020-02-02        23       NaN            0
2  2020-02-03        14       start          0
3  2020-02-04        23       start          0
4  2020-02-05        23       start          0
5  2020-02-06        23       NaN            0
6  2020-02-07        30       foundation     0
7  2020-02-08        29       foundation     0
8  2020-02-09       100       NaN            0
9  2020-02-10        38       learn          0
10 2020-02-11        38       learn          0
11 2020-02-12        38       learn          0
12 2020-02-13        70       NaN            0
13 2020-02-14        70       practice       0
14 2020-02-15        38       NaN            0
15 2020-02-16        38       NaN            0
16 2020-02-17        70       exam           0
17 2020-02-18        70       exam           0
18 2020-02-19        38       exam           0
19 2020-02-20        38       NaN            0
20 2020-02-21        70       NaN            0
21 2020-02-22        70       test           0
22 2020-02-23        38       test           0
23 2020-02-24        38       NaN            0
24 2020-02-25        70       NaN            0
25 2020-02-26        70       NaN            0
26 2020-02-27        70       NaN            0
```

df2:

```
From                to                   plan          score
2020-02-03          2020-02-05           start         20
2020-02-07          2020-02-08           foundation    25
2020-02-10          2020-02-12           learn         10
2020-02-14          2020-02-16           practice      20
2020-02-15          2020-02-21           exam          30
2020-02-20          2020-02-23           test          10
```

From the above I would like to add a column `plan_score` in df1 based df2 `plan` and `score` value.

Explanation:

Step1: Initialise df1['plan_score'] = 0.

```
df1['plan_score'] = 0
```

Step2: update `df1['plan_score']` based on `df1['plan']`, `df2['plan']` and `df2['score']`.

For example if I wants to update 3rd row (index=2), i.e df1['plan_score'] at row 3,

Where `plan = 'start'`

```
df1['plan_score'] = df1['plan_score'](previuos value) + ((df1['score'] when `plan = 'start'`)/count(df2['plan'] == 'start'))


df1['plan_score'](previuos value) = 0, second index value

(df1['score'] when `plan = 'start'`) = 20

count(df1['plan'] == 'start') = 3

in this case 0 + (20/3) = 6.67.
```

Step3: If df1['plan'] == NaN, then replace with previous value.

So the expected output.

```
 Date           t_factor      plan           plan_score       plan_score_final
0  2020-02-01         5       NaN            0                0
1  2020-02-02        23       NaN            0                0
2  2020-02-03        14       start          0                0 + (20/3)=6.67
3  2020-02-04        23       start          0                6.67 + (20/3) = 13.37
4  2020-02-05        23       start          0                13.37 + (20/3) = 20.04
5  2020-02-06        23       NaN            0                20.04
6  2020-02-07        30       foundation     0                20.04 + (25/2) = 32.54
7  2020-02-08        29       foundation     0                32.54 + (25/2) = 45.04
8  2020-02-09       100       NaN            0                45.04
9  2020-02-10        38       learn          0                45.04 + (10/3) = 48.37
10 2020-02-11        38       learn          0                48.37 + (10/3) = 51.70
11 2020-02-12        38       learn          0                51.70 + (10/3) = 55.03
12 2020-02-13        70       NaN            0                55.03
13 2020-02-14        70       practice       0                55.03 + (20/1) = 75.03
14 2020-02-15        38       NaN            0                75.03
15 2020-02-16        38       NaN            0                75.03
16 2020-02-17        70       exam           0                75.03 + (30/10) = 85.03
17 2020-02-18        70       exam           0                85.03 + (30/10) = 95.03
18 2020-02-19        38       exam           0                95.03 + (30/10) = 105.03
19 2020-02-20        38       NaN            0                105.03
20 2020-02-21        70       NaN            0                105.03
21 2020-02-22        70       test           0                105.03 + (10/2) = 110.03
22 2020-02-23        38       test           0                110.03 + (10/2) = 115.03
23 2020-02-24        38       NaN            0                115.03
24 2020-02-25        70       NaN            0                115.03
25 2020-02-26        70       NaN            0                115.03
26 2020-02-27        70       NaN            0                115.03
```

Important Note:

in df2, I will be having `score1`, `score2` and `score3`, by using the same method I would like to create `plan_score1`, `plan_score2`, and `plan_score3`.

We can delete `plan_score` and rename `plan_score_final` as `plan_score` for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
c = pd.Index(['score']) # score1, score2, score3 can be added

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2[c.union(['From'])], left_on='Date', right_on='From')
freq = df['plan'].map(df['plan'].value_counts())

df['plan_' + c] = df[c].div(freq, axis=0).cumsum().round(2).ffill().fillna(0)
df = df.drop(cols.union(['From']), 1)
```

**Details:**

Use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to `asof` merge dataframes `df1` and `df2` on the corresponding columns `Date` and `From`:

```
print(df)
          Date  t_factor        plan  plan_score       From  score
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN           0        NaT    NaN
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN           0        NaT    NaN
2  2020-02-03        14       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0
3  2020-02-04        23       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0
4  2020-02-05        23       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0
5  2020-02-06        23         NaN           0 2020-02-03   20.0
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation           0 2020-02-07   25.0
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation           0 2020-02-07   25.0
8  2020-02-09       100         NaN           0 2020-02-07   25.0
9  2020-02-10        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0
10 2020-02-11        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0
11 2020-02-12        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0
12 2020-02-13        70         NaN           0 2020-02-10   10.0
13 2020-02-14        70    practice           0 2020-02-14   20.0
14 2020-02-15        38         NaN           0 2020-02-15   30.0
15 2020-02-16        38         NaN           0 2020-02-15   30.0
16 2020-02-17        70        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0
17 2020-02-18        70        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0
18 2020-02-19        38        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0
19 2020-02-20        38         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
20 2020-02-21        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
21 2020-02-22        70        test           0 2020-02-20   10.0
22 2020-02-23        38        test           0 2020-02-20   10.0
23 2020-02-24        38         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
24 2020-02-25        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
25 2020-02-26        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
26 2020-02-27        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0
```

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to map the values in `plan` column to their corresponding frequencies of occurrence.

```
print(freq)
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     NaN
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     NaN
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    NaN
13    1.0
14    NaN
15    NaN
16    3.0
17    3.0
18    3.0
19    NaN
20    NaN
21    2.0
22    2.0
23    NaN
24    NaN
25    NaN
26    NaN
Name: plan, dtype: float64
```

Finally use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to create `plan_score` columns corresponding to the score columns in `df2`, next use [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to drop the unwanted columns:

```
print(df)
         Date  t_factor        plan  plan_score
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN        0.00
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN        0.00
2  2020-02-03        14       start        6.67
3  2020-02-04        23       start       13.33
4  2020-02-05        23       start       20.00
5  2020-02-06        23         NaN       20.00
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation       32.50
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation       45.00
8  2020-02-09       100         NaN       45.00
9  2020-02-10        38       learn       48.33
10 2020-02-11        38       learn       51.67
11 2020-02-12        38       learn       55.00
12 2020-02-13        70         NaN       55.00
13 2020-02-14        70    practice       75.00
14 2020-02-15        38         NaN       75.00
15 2020-02-16        38         NaN       75.00
16 2020-02-17        70        exam       85.00
17 2020-02-18        70        exam       95.00
18 2020-02-19        38        exam      105.00
19 2020-02-20        38         NaN      105.00
20 2020-02-21        70         NaN      105.00
21 2020-02-22        70        test      110.00
22 2020-02-23        38        test      115.00
23 2020-02-24        38         NaN      115.00
24 2020-02-25        70         NaN      115.00
25 2020-02-26        70         NaN      115.00
26 2020-02-27        70         NaN      115.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge.asof` on the dates, then get score by `groupby` and `count`, finally do a `cumsum`:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df2["From"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["From"])

new = pd.merge_asof(df, df2[["From","score"]], left_on="Date", right_on="From", direction="backward")
s = new.loc[new["plan"].notnull()].groupby("plan")["plan"].transform("count")
new["final"] = (new["score"]*(1/s)).fillna(0).cumsum()

print (new)

         Date  t_factor        plan  plan_score       From  score       final
0  2020-02-01         5         NaN           0        NaT    NaN    0.000000
1  2020-02-02        23         NaN           0        NaT    NaN    0.000000
2  2020-02-03        14       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0    6.666667
3  2020-02-04        23       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0   13.333333
4  2020-02-05        23       start           0 2020-02-03   20.0   20.000000
5  2020-02-06        23         NaN           0 2020-02-03   20.0   20.000000
6  2020-02-07        30  foundation           0 2020-02-07   25.0   32.500000
7  2020-02-08        29  foundation           0 2020-02-07   25.0   45.000000
8  2020-02-09       100         NaN           0 2020-02-07   25.0   45.000000
9  2020-02-10        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0   48.333333
10 2020-02-11        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0   51.666667
11 2020-02-12        38       learn           0 2020-02-10   10.0   55.000000
12 2020-02-13        70         NaN           0 2020-02-10   10.0   55.000000
13 2020-02-14        70    practice           0 2020-02-14   20.0   75.000000
14 2020-02-15        38         NaN           0 2020-02-15   30.0   75.000000
15 2020-02-16        38         NaN           0 2020-02-15   30.0   75.000000
16 2020-02-17        70        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0   85.000000
17 2020-02-18        70        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0   95.000000
18 2020-02-19        38        exam           0 2020-02-15   30.0  105.000000
19 2020-02-20        38         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  105.000000
20 2020-02-21        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  105.000000
21 2020-02-22        70        test           0 2020-02-20   10.0  110.000000
22 2020-02-23        38        test           0 2020-02-20   10.0  115.000000
23 2020-02-24        38         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  115.000000
24 2020-02-25        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  115.000000
25 2020-02-26        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  115.000000
26 2020-02-27        70         NaN           0 2020-02-20   10.0  115.000000
```

Comment: in df2 I will be having score1, score2 and score3, so I have to calculate, plan_score1, plan_score2 and plan_score3.

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: Is this code works for if df2 has score1, score2 column and I have to create plan_score1 and plan_score2.

Comment: If df2['score'] == NaN replace with previous value

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Please look into below question during your free time.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63355481/export-two-data-frames-as-one-excel-file-with-two-sheets-in-pandas-on-specified