# Export two data frames as one excel file with two sheets in pandas on specified location

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe as shown below.

df1:

```
   Date           t_factor    plan           plan_score
0  2020-02-01         5       NaN            0
1  2020-02-02        23       NaN            0
2  2020-02-03        14       start          0
3  2020-02-04        23       start          0
4  2020-02-05        23       start          0
5  2020-02-06        23       NaN            0
6  2020-02-07        30       foundation     0
7  2020-02-08        29       foundation     0
8  2020-02-09       100       NaN            0
9  2020-02-10        38       learn          0
10 2020-02-11        38       learn          0
11 2020-02-12        38       learn          0
12 2020-02-13        70       NaN            0
13 2020-02-14        70       practice       0
14 2020-02-15        38       NaN            0
15 2020-02-16        38       NaN            0
16 2020-02-17        70       exam           0
17 2020-02-18        70       exam           0
18 2020-02-19        38       exam           0
19 2020-02-20        38       NaN            0
20 2020-02-21        70       NaN            0
21 2020-02-22        70       test           0
22 2020-02-23        38       test           0
23 2020-02-24        38       NaN            0
24 2020-02-25        70       NaN            0
25 2020-02-26        70       NaN            0
26 2020-02-27        70       NaN            0
```

df2:

```
From                to                   plan          score
2020-02-03          2020-02-05           start         20
2020-02-07          2020-02-08           foundation    25
2020-02-10          2020-02-12           learn         10
2020-02-14          2020-02-16           practice      20
2020-02-15          2020-02-21           exam          30
2020-02-20          2020-02-23           test          10
```

Explanation:

I have loaded the both dataframe in pandas and I would like to export this dataframes as 1 excel file with Sheet1 = df1 and Sheet2 = df2.

I tried below.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
            df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
        writer.save()

save_xls([df1, df2], os.getcwd())
```

And it is giving me following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OptionError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __new__(cls, path, engine, **kwargs)
    630                 try:
--> 631                     engine = config.get_option(f"io.excel.{ext}.writer")
    632                     if engine == "auto":

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_config/config.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    230     def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
--> 231         return self.__func__(*args, **kwds)
    232 

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_config/config.py in _get_option(pat, silent)
    101 def _get_option(pat, silent=False):
--> 102     key = _get_single_key(pat, silent)
    103 

~/admvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_config/config.py in _get_single_key(pat, silent)
     87             _warn_if_deprecated(pat)
---> 88         raise OptionError(f"No such keys(s): {repr(pat)}")
     89     if len(keys) > 1:

OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'io.excel..writer'"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-80bc8a5d0d2f> in <module>
----> 1 save_xls([df1, df2], os.getcwd())

<ipython-input-15-0d1448e7aea8> in save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path)
      1 def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
----> 2     with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
      3         for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
      4             df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
      5         writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working specify excel file like:

```
import os
    
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
            df.to_excel(writer,'sheet%s' % n)
        writer.save()

save_xls([df1, df2], 'file.xlsx')
```